# Specifying xml parsing with multiple roots having the same name using etree

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse an xml file in the form-

```
<element> 
   <status>OK</status> 
   <duration> 
    <value>340110</value> 
    <text>3 jours 22 heures</text> 
   </duration> 
   <distance> 
    <value>1734542</value> 
    <text>1 735 km</text> 
   </distance> 
  </element>
```

I am then separating out the time values and comparing them to get the smallest possible value. However, I'm not sure how to do this without also ending up getting the distance value, which messes up my dataset. This is the code I have so far for fetching anything under the values root-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
times=[]
for i in htmlSource:
    root=ET.fromstring(i)
    for value in root.iter('value'):
        times.append(value.text)
```

Is there a way I can modify this to only get the values under duration and not distance? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to figure this one out. I also needed to keep the index of the values true to the original data, which was difficult because any time the status of the element changed there would be no 'value' portion and the index of all following values would be bumped up from the absence. This was my solution for both that problem and my original one.

```
for i in htmlSource: 
    root=ET.fromstring(i) #parses the data
    for element in root.iter('element'):
        if element[0].text == 'OK'
            Temp=element[1][0].text #finds the time value
            times.append(Temp) #adds the time value to a list
        else:
            times.append(0)
```

The element[1][0] indicates the first 'child' of the second root of the element specified, which is the needed value root, and the .text gives me the text contents of that root. The element[0] is the status, the first root under the element.